# How to run Ruby 2.0 with JRuby 1.7?

Tags: ruby, jruby, ruby-2.0

What is the best way to get JRuby to run in 2.0 mode?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For a specific script, you can use the `--2.0` option:

```
jruby --2.0 -S rails s
```

For setting 2.0 as the default value, set `JRUBY_OPTS`:

```
export JRUBY_OPTS=--2.0
```

You can also set the value in `~/.jrubyrc`:

```
compat.version=2.0
```

Comment: It's still work in progress, though, but you can start playing with it.

Comment: Ruby 2.0 is compatible with 1.9.x syntax, so if JRuby is 1.9.x compatible it should by default work with 2.0. Perhaps the way JRuby uses the JVM may cause problems with 2.0. I'm just starting to look at JRuby; hopefully it will work well with Ruby 2.0.

Comment: @AdrienLamothe any suggestions based on your experience thus far?

Comment: FYI -- JRuby 1.7.4 has "experimental support" for Ruby 2.0 - http://jruby.org/2013/05/16/jruby-1-7-4

Comment: @AdrienLamothe `Ruby 2.0 is compatible with 1.9.x syntax` <- you mean 1.9.x accepts `%i(a b)` ?