# running jruby on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, jruby

I'm trying to run a Ruby on Rails application on Heroku with jruby in 2.0 mode.

My gemfile contains

```
ruby '2.0.0', engine: "jruby", engine_version: "1.7.18"
```

and it works locally if I set jruby to run in 2.0 mode with an env variable, eg:

```
JRUBY_OPTS=--2.0 bundle install
```

without, I get the usual version mismatch error:

```
bundle install
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

#### The question:

How can I make jruby run in 2.0 mode without env variables? How can I make it the default?

Should I set them in the `Procfile`? in the binstubbed executables under `app_root/bin/`?

Comment: do you get after `$ruby -v` `jruby-` in heroku console

Comment: inlocally do you get` jruby` after `bundle install`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Ruby 2.0 with JRuby 1.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281036/how-to-run-ruby-2-0-with-jruby-1-7)